# What's the purpose of locking an array in multithreaded code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I've been reading through some code that supports multithreading and found this:

```
FileInfo[] _files;

//later
lock(_files) 
{
     var pold = (byte) ((_bytesWrittenOld*100)/_bytesCount);
     _bytesWritten += e.Value;
     byte pnow;
     if (_bytesCount < _bytesWritten)
     {
          pnow = 100;
     }
     else
     {
           pnow = (byte)((_bytesWritten * 100) / _bytesCount);
     }
     if (pnow > pold)
     {
          _bytesWrittenOld = _bytesWritten;
          OnCompressing(new ProgressEventArgs(pnow, (byte) (pnow - pold)));
     }
}
```

Inside that lock statement, _files field isn't touched or even accessed. 
Can someone explain what's the purpose of this lock **other than to prevent multi-threaded access**? 
I don't think locking array of `FileInfo` instances will lock the corresponding file-system entries 
**UPD** this is the only place where the lock is held against this variable in this class. Fields `_bytesCount, _bytesWritten, _bytesWrittenOld` are updated in multiple other places without entering any locks (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Post the entire code otherwise it's a bit impossible say what do "some actions"

Comment: For locking you can use any object instance and only one thread context is allowed to work inside this lock. Thats the whole story

Comment: Is there any *other* place that locks `_files` ? Does *that* place manipulates `_bytesWrittenOld`, `_bytesCount` or `_bytesWritten` ?

Comment: BTW raising events (`OnCompressing`) while holding a lock is asking for trouble (re-entrancy, deadlocks etc).

Comment: I did not see any point where _files is locked. Instead there is a lock identified by an instance reference. It does not lock anything else.

Comment: @MickyD I hear you. will post more code

Comment: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @Tinwor I've posted an update

Comment: @RemusRusanu I posted an update